# MYSQL result in specific table format to show on result page

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am using VS 2010, MYSQL, ASP.Net, C#.
I need to create following structure on my ASPX page.
I got required result by query, but now i need to create that DESCRIPTION part of image in single row. please help me, how to get this done?

[image]

```
Select tbladjustment.colId,tbladjustment.colDate,
CASE
WHEN ( tbladjustmentdetail.colDebit is null ) = true THEN 'Credit'
WHEN ( tbladjustmentdetail.colCredit is null ) = true THEN 'Debit'
ELSE 'Status'
END AS DRCR,
tblaccounts.colAccName,  tbladjustmentdetail.colDebit,
tbladjustmentdetail.colCredit,
tblcurrency.Currency,tbladjustment.colMemo
from tbladjustment
inner join tbladjustmentdetail on tbladjustment.colId=tbladjustmentdetail.colAdjustId
inner join tblcurrency on tbladjustmentdetail.colCurrencyId=tblcurrency.ColId
inner join tblaccounts on tbladjustmentdetail.colAccId=tblaccounts.colAccId
where tbladjustment.colCompanyId= 8 && tbladjustment.colIsDeleted=0 &&         tblladjustmentdetail.colIsDeleted=0;
```